# How to add data of one table to another table in mysql both table having same column names?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query which is causing the following error-

> MySQL 1062 - Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY' INSERT INTO TABLE3
>   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 UNION SELECT * FROM TABLE2;

Answer (score 0):

You have a primary key in table3. You are duplicating it. Try to run

```
select * 
from 
table1 
union 
select * 
from table2
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```

and see which id causes the duplication